# Quill 2.0.0 beta4 auto syntax highlight doesnt work

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quill

I read through quill's guide for syntax highlighting but couldn't get it to work, as quill kept complaining about highlight.js not being loaded first.

I have tried numerous solutions online, but none have worked. I get a selector for language instead (which in my local project, when saved as html and reopened, also adds unnecessary p tags with language names).

Here is a sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/importing-sass-in-vue-forked-skuss?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

I imported highlight.js via cdn directly on index.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED**

As per requested, the requirement is to disable the selection box and do the syntax highlight automatically.

Since quill 2.0.0, there is a huge change on how syntax highlight works where selecting language becomes mandatory.

In order to achieve the goal, we need to override the quill Syntax class.

```js
class CodeSyntax extends Syntax {
  // override initListener to avoid creating selection box
  initListener() {}
  
  // overrider highlightBlot to highlight the text automatically
  highlightBlot(text, language = 'plain') {
    const container = this.quill.root.ownerDocument.createElement('div');
    container.classList.add(CodeBlock.className);
    container.innerHTML = this.options.hljs.highlightAuto(text).value;
    ...
  }
}
```

```js
mounted() {
    const editorOpts = {
      modules: {
        syntax: {
          hljs // inject highlight.js to quill
        },
        toolbar: {
          container: [
            [{ header: [1, 2, 3, false] }],
            ["bold", "italic", "underline", "code-block"],
          ],
        },
      },
      theme: "snow",
    };
    editorOpts["scrollingContainer"] = this.$refs.scrollingContainer;
    
    // override the default syntax module with our own version of it
    Quill.register({ "modules/syntax": CodeSyntax }, true);
    this.editorInstance = new Quill(this.$refs.editorNode, editorOpts);
},
```

Codesandbox seems like cannot handle overriding package class correctly. I uploaded [the code in Github](https://github.com/michael-vascue/test-quill-highlight).

P.S. I just use css instead of scss for simplicity.

[image]

---

I think you are just missing the highlightjs css only.

https://codesandbox.io/s/importing-sass-in-vue-forked-fympz?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue:1717-1758

```css
@import "highlight.js/styles/github.css";
```

import it and test it again, the syntax should be hightlighted.
[image]

Comment: I think you misunderstood. The css is imported in main.js already (Since the rendered html will be used in places where quill might not be instantiated...

The ***AUTO*** syntax highlighting is not working as intended as demonstrated in this pen https://codepen.io/0stone0/pen/poJwBzw (older version of highlightjs and quill).

PS: I do not want the selector. :)

Comment: ok. but i cannot see the css is imported in main.js in the codesandbox. so the main problem is to remove the selector and do the auto highlight automatically, right?

Comment: Yes.... I think I accidentally removed the css... Sorry about that.

Comment: no problem. but may take some time to read the source code. may not be able to reply you today.

Comment: updated answer, please check the code on github. codesandbox has error on overriding third party packages.

Comment: I am sorry for the delay. But I get an error that `class constructors must be invoked with 'new'` on the line where quill is initialized (HelloWorld.vue:68 in your code) which then bubbles to line 62 on codeSyntax.js but there is no line 62...  Here is the rest of the stack trace https://imgur.com/ISKlr4f QuillEditor.vue:152 is the exact same line as HelloWorld.vue:68 in your github repo

Comment: you are using vue-cli to create project or using pure webpack?

Comment: and are your babel setting same as the codesandbox you share? If yes, I think there is a problem in your `env` block in the babel. if you remove the entire `env`, the error will be gone.  https://codesandbox.io/s/importing-sass-in-vue-forked-fympz?file=/src/components/codeSyntax.js

i don't have much knowledge on your `env` settings, I only know `@babel/preset-env`. may need you to figure out the `env` setting on how to include class interoperation.

Comment: i didnt have dynamic import node but even then I get the same error.

Comment: but if you run my code, is there any error? If no, then It is better if you can share the repo to me to debug. Quite hard to guess where the error come from if your babel setting changed as well. no error on my code and on the codesandbox, it will be hard to simulate the error. 

Comment: Unfortunately I cant.... I tried to copy over the babelrc as well to no avail. I will mark this as the answer. Thank you for your effort!